# Can I Submit An App To App Store If It's Only Usable For 1 Person?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I've seen Apple's documentation about Enterprise Program Apps (see: [Distributing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html))

I have an app that is made only for a specific user, say a store owner. And so that app can only be used by such owner. It's called the **MyStore Admin** (something like that). Basically it's like a CMS, used for managing all the users of the whole project and the data and everything for administrator. It's under the development.

Furthermore, I have a client app for his business that is on the App Store already and is available for everyone.

So back to my main question, can I submit the admin app to the App Store even though it can only be used by 1 person? They can't use the app unless they have an admin account provided by the company.

Comment: Just go through the review guidlines and decide https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Yes , u can publish, Check this link also https://www.quora.com/Can-I-submit-An-App-To-App-Store-If-Its-Only-Usable-For-1-Person

Comment: Thank you for your answer @iTamilan. Also, I posted that specific question on Quora! :P haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can publish the app.

Create one demo user and provide those details in iTunes description as well. So technically everyone can use the app. I also seen lot of apps like that. Make sure that demo account can able to access every feature of app.

And also can check your app meets these guidelines
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#before-you-submit

Check this app for reference

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/livecare-connectm/id1020817716?mt=8

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because of your phrase: "Yes we can publish the app. (with conviction). Also the "I also seen lot of apps like that". No problem with the rejection stuff. I already have apps on the App Store. Case closed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if an app only used by few user, you should prepare a build & distribute the build over the air with tools like test flight or crashlytics.

Comment: That's right. Now here are the points why I asked this question. You can distribute indeed the app via test flight, but it will expire soon, so you'll need to upload a new build every now and then. Crashlytics is quite a pain the as* because since the client (2 or less people) and I are from different countries, I would have to ask them for their UUIDs or ask them to take some steps in order for me to get their UUIDs and then let them download again the new build with new provisioning profile. As a mid iOS developer, uploading this kind of app to app store is a point too in my resume :).